# Python: NumPy divide line by sum or replace it by another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

i am currently trying to obtain a matrice using the NumPy library, but there is a problem that i cannot find the solution to

I currently have the following numpy array

```
mat = 
[[0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Now i want to divide each line by the sum of the line, but if the sum of the line is equal to zero, i replace it by a line of `1/len(mat)`. I tried to use the following code:

```
    for line in mat:
        line /= np.sum(line)
        mat[np.isnan(mat)] = 1/N
```

The following code will return:

```
[[0.         0.5        0.5        0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.         0.         0.33333333 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.5       ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.         0.5       ]
 [0.         0.         0.         1.         0.         0.        ]]
```

This is the correct result i was trying to get, but it gives `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide`.

**So I was wondering if there was a better way to get the correct result, so i don't have to check after each line if the line if full of `nan`**. (Also if there is a way to instantly divide each line by the sum of each line, instead of have to use the `for` loop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by the sum row-wise and fill `NaN` with `1/len(mat)`

```
np.nan_to_num(                     # Function to replace non-finite values with given value
    np.divide(                     # Divide function
        mat,                       # Input array for division
        mat.sum(axis=1)[:, None]   # Sum across axis=1(across row) and transpose them for division
    ),
    nan=1/len(mat)                 # value that will replace non-finite values
)
```

One-liner

```
np.nan_to_num(np.divide(mat, mat.sum(axis=1)[:, None]), nan=1/len(mat))
```

Output

```
[[0.         0.5        0.5        0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.         0.         0.33333333 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.5       ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.         0.5       ]
 [0.         0.         0.         1.         0.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: Amazing! However, could it be possible to get a 'detailed version'. I am a huge fan of one-liners, but since i haven't really ever used `numpy` i am having a hard time understanding

Comment: @needle Have added function by function explanation

Comment: Thank you, i was just wondering, but your code also give `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide`. Is that not really a problem? Or is their maybe an easy way to fix it?

Comment: @needle When you divide by zero, it creates an `inf` (infinity) value. Numpy just warns you so that you are aware of it. If you don't want it popping up you could disable it using `np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')`. But it is helpful sometimes when it is not intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [-1,0,1]])
s = mat.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)  # sum of each line
out = np.ones_like(mat).astype(np.float) / len(mat)  # initialize with 1/N
not_zeros = s[:,0]!=0  # logical indexes of noz zero sum lines 
out[not_zeros, :] = mat[not_zeros, :] / s[not_zeros] # normalize onlt the non zero sum lines
print(out)

[[0.16666667 0.33333333 0.5       ]
 [0.26666667 0.33333333 0.4       ]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333]]
```

Update - zero sum lines are 1/N

Comment: your method seems to only work partially, because i would to have it so that it remplaces any row that is filled with ALL zeros, by a row filled by `1/len(mat)`. I tried using your code on the numpy array `mat = [[0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]`. It almost worked, except for the row filled with zeros

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[0. ,1. ,1., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0. ,0.],
 [1. ,1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0. ,1., 1.],
 [0. ,0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
 [0. ,0. ,0. ,1. ,0., 0.]])
```

```py
sum_ = np.sum(mat, axis=1)

mat[(sum_==0), :] = 1/len(mat) # handle where sum==0
mat[~(sum_==0), :] /= sum_[~(sum_==0), np.newaxis] # handle where sum not 0

mat
```

```
array([[0.        , 0.5       , 0.5       , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667,
        0.16666667],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.5       ,
        0.5       ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.5       , 0.        ,
        0.5       ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]])
```